# Newby struggling with very simple Python / HTML routine

Tags: python, html, flask

please be gentle. I'm trying to learn some Python / Flask and HTML and for a very simple exercise I'm trying to write a routine that:

Opens a web browser locally.
Prompts the user to select a local image
Displays the image on the web page.

It's all local stuff - eventually I'd like to move this into the cloud but right now I'm just trying to get it to work locally.

However when my program executes I am not getting a full image - only a generic "uploaded Photo" icon.

The upload screen:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Here is my code:

FlyFinderWeb.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_photo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'photo' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        photo = request.files['photo']
        
        if photo.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        if photo:
            filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], photo.filename)
            photo.save(filename)
            return redirect(url_for('display_photo', filename=photo.filename))
    
    return render_template('upload.html')


@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_photo(filename):
    print(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))  
    return render_template('display.html', filename=filename)



app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True) #automatically restart server if changes are detected  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Upload.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload and Display Photo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload a Photo Please 3.0</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="photo" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" title="Select File">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Display.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Photo</title>
    <style>
        .image-container {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom:;
        }
        .image-container img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Uploaded Photo</h1>

    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="{{ url_for('display_photo', filename=filename) }}" alt="Uploaded Photo">

    </div>
    
    <p>Would you like to repeat another?</p>
    <a href="{{ url_for('upload_photo') }}">Upload Another</a>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the directory structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully managed to upload the photo. When viewing, however, you should distinguish between the file name and the image data. The client cannot access the image directly using the name, but needs the image data to display the image, which can be sent by the server using the file name.

To serve the image data you need another endpoint.

```py
@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download_photo(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.abspath(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']), 
        filename
    )
```

Then it is necessary to change the URL for the src attribute of the img tag in the `display.html` file.

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="{{ url_for('download_photo', filename=filename) }}" alt="Uploaded Photo">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to build an image recognition routine in tensorflow which I have running locally but now want to get it running on the web.  This fixed that particular issue!  Really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad if your question was answered with that. So click the tick to signal this and gain further privileges through additional points.